# Can I know what I'm looking at from the URL?

Tags: 8, uri

I think on Drupal 7 I had previously used something like `menu_get_object()` to find out what content I was on. For example, with mysite.com/content/my-page, it would tell me that this was a node, its content type, its ID, etc.

Ideally I'm trying to do it even if the URL is the site's front page, I'd like to be able to reverse engineer what content it is showing me.

Comment: What's your end goal? Knowing that might get you suggestions for different (perhaps better) approaches

Comment: @Clive, I already have a system that is sending analytics data based on the URL the user is on, but it can get confused if the default homepage is set to something else within the site, because they could have visited the homepage anonymous or authenticated. Unfortunately I'm not building it for a once use case, it's for multiple sites, so that's why I want something kinda open-ended for any of my platforms I send it to

Comment: Which is why I wanted to see if there was an easy enough way to get Drupal to tell me what page you are on, so that I could also send that data, as well as just my URL

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense. I think that's quite difficult to do generically, as the answer below mentions you can do it per-entity type easily enough but I think you'll need to test for all of the different things the page could be manually, rather than Drupal telling you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for a route parameter, which is automatically upcasted to an entity object if you are on an entity route.

For example on a node route:

```
use Drupal\node\NodeInterface;

  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if ($node instanceof NodeInterface) {
    $content_type = $node->getType();
    $id = $node->id();
  }
```

Comment: Ah excellent, thank you